# Why premature eof on this flex program?

Tags: c, flex-lexer, eof, lex

I am making a program in flex that takes a user's input in the form of a string that describes a shape.
Now my code seems correct, but I get a premature eof on compilation.

I have also tried doing what similar questions have as answers, but still nothing.

```
%{
int flag = 0; 
}%
%%
"point" + [A-H]|"line" + [A-H]{2}|"triangle" + [A-H]{3}|"square" + [A-H]{4}|"pentagon" + [A-H] {5}|"hexagon" + [A-H]{6}|"heptagon" + [A-H]{7}|"octagon" + [A-H]{8}
flag=1; 
%%
main(){
    yylex();
    if (flag == 1){ 
        printf("Accepted");
    }else{
        printf("Not accepted");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `%{` is unclosed because you wrote `}%` instead of `%}`. So flex thinks the `}%` and everything after it is supposed to be part of the C code and is still waiting for a closing `%}` when it reached the end of the file.

Comment: i did also try that but then i get more errors , propable regarding the the rest of the code , like :  flex5.l:5:3: error: expected expression before '[' token
 "point" + [A-H]|"line" + [A-H]{2}|"triangle" + [A-H]{3}|"square" + [A-H]{4}|"pentagon" + [A-H]{5}|"hexagon" + [A-H]{6}|"heptagon" + [A-H]{7}|"octagon" + [A-H]{8}
   ^

Comment: @AlVa Yes, that's an unrelated error from the rest of the code. Specifically everything after the first space in `"point" + [A-H]|"line" ...` is interpreted as C code, but since it clearly isn't valid C code, it does not compile. The general syntax of lex/flex is `pattern code` where everything up to the first space is seen as the regex pattern and the rest of the line is seen as C code. If you want spaces in your regex, they need to be inside quotes (or brackets or escaped with a backslash). Also note that if you intend `flag=1;` to be the C action, it should be on the same line.

Comment: thank you for your help , i deleted the spaces in the regular expression but kept the flag=1; in the same line it was since it is the only C code i am using there . After inputing something like pointA which should be correct since it uses "point" and only 1 character from [A-H] i get the "Not accepted method" even though my flag should be equal to 1 cause the input was correct , thanks in advance

Comment: @AlVa If you kept the C code on its own line, it's interpreted as a regex and it won't be executed. If you want it to be executed when the pattern is seen, it needs to be on the same line as the pattern separated by a space. If you still have problems after that, please post a new question with your current code, the input you're entering, your expected output and the actual output.

Comment: thank my friend i did what you told me but i forgot to update my question , everything runs smoothly my friend , thank you very much